# Custom taxonomy page not working

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom taxonomy 'animal-species' that I want to filter out my 'animals' custom post type. The idea is that a user can go to the main animals page and filter them out by cats, dogs etc. I've created a taxonomy-animals-animal-species.php page, but the domain.com/animals/?animal-species=cat (or dog or whatever) still lists all of the animals, not just the ones that match the taxonomy. I've tried re-naming the taxonomy page to every variation that I can think of with no success. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

TLDR: domain.com/animals/?animal-species=cat and domain.com/animals/ give the same results

Code for both the animal-listing.php page and taxonomy-animals-animal-species.php pages

```
<?php
            $page_link = get_permalink();
            $animal_species = get_terms( 'animal-species' );

            $args = array();
            $args['post_type'] = 'animal';
            if ( isset( $_GET['animal-species'] ) ) {
                $args['animal-species'] = $_GET['animal-species'];
                $page_link = add_query_arg( 'animal-species', $_GET['animal-species'], $page_link );
            }

            if ( is_array( $animal_species ) ) {
                echo '<ul class="species_list">';
                echo '<li><a href="' . htmlentities( remove_query_arg( 'animal-species', $page_link ) ) . '">Show all animals</a></li>';
                foreach ( $animal_species as $animal_species ) {
                    echo '<li><a href="' . htmlentities( add_query_arg( 'animal-species', $animal_species->slug, $page_link ) ) . '">' . $animal_species->name . 's</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        ?>


            <div class="listing">
                    <?php 
                        $animals_per_page = 10;

                        if( function_exists( 'ot_get_option' ) )
                        {                               
                            $animals_per_page = intval(ot_get_option('animals_per_page'));
                        }

                        $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'animal',
                                    'posts_per_page' => $animals_per_page,
                                    'paged' => $paged
                                );

                        $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                        $i = 0;                     
                        if ( $query->have_posts() ) 
                        {

                            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : 

                                $query->the_post(); 
                                $i++;

                                    ?>                          
                                    <div class="animal-item <?php if ($i % 2 == 0) { echo "even"; } ?>" >
                                        <?php get_template_part( 'inc/display-animal' ); ?>                        
                                    </div>                           
                                    <?php

                            endwhile;
                        }
                ?>                          
            </div>
```

Comment: Without the code for the page this is going to be difficult to answer.

Comment: The main animal-listing.php page, taxonomy-animals-animal-species.php is identical

Answer (score 1):

You're not querying for a specific taxonomy term, you set `$args['animal-species']`, but then you overwrite the `$args` var later, before the query. also, that form of taxonomy query is deprecated, see [`tax_query` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Comment: Could you give me a working example?

Comment: a working example of what exactly? tax_query parameters are shown on the page I linked, substitute your taxonomy and term names.